# Straightening tilted viewport

Tags: 3d-view, camera

[image]

[image]

I am not sure how I got that tilt. How can I get the viewport to be correctly aligned again?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift while moving the mouse's scroll wheel to rotate the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the viewport camera, simply hit <kbd>NUMPAD1</kbd>, <kbd>NUMPAD3</kbd> or <kbd>NUMPAD7</kbd> to get into an aligend view. Alternatively use the View menu (Right, Front or Top).

If your camera object got tilted, open the properties with <kbd>N</kbd>, find the rotation values in the Transform panel and find the value that isn't quite 90 or 0 degrees and enter a clean value.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**C**</kbd> will re-center the camera on the origin. It is possible this tilt is acquired from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num4</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num6</kbd> which control the roll of the camera.
As @Haunt_House mentioned, the <kbd>N</kbd> panel has all camera translation information, which you can change manually if desired.